How to define a Record of Angular Components that inherit from an abstract class with an InputSignal property?
I try to define a Record like this:
// imports...

export abstract class AbstractComponent<T extends string> {
  abstract prop: InputSignal<T>;
}

export class TestComponent extends AbstractComponent<'test'> {
  prop: InputSignal<'test'> = input('test');
}

@Component({ standalone: true, template: `` })
export class App {
  component: Record<string, typeof AbstractComponent<string>> = {
    'test-1': TestComponent,
  };
}

And I get this error:
Type 'typeof TestComponent' is not assignable to type 'typeof AbstractComponent<string>'.
  Construct signature return types 'TestComponent' and 'AbstractComponent<string>' are incompatible.
    The types of 'prop[SIGNAL].transformFn' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '((value: "test") => "test") | undefined' is not assignable to type '((value: string) => string) | undefined'.
        Type '(value: "test") => "test"' is not assignable to type '(value: string) => string'.
          Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"test"'.(2322)


In the real project, the T extends string generic is an interface and the 'test' literal type is its sub-type.
The Record's values have to be type-safe so that it was not possible to assign component = { 'a': null } or pass a type that doesn't extend string to the signal

How do I fix the error?

Simple StackBlitz demo
Complex StackBlitz demo


After a whole day of trial, error and confusion i've come up with this:
export class App {
  component: Record<string, typeof AbstractComponent<string>> = {
    'test-1': TestComponent as typeof AbstractComponent<string>,
  };
}

I've also made a more complex demo of why I have so many restrictions and concerns about type safety. It's also available on StackBlitz.
import { Component, InputSignal, input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

interface MyType<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
  value: T;
}

export abstract class AbstractComponent<T extends MyType> {
  abstract prop: InputSignal<T>;
}

type Test1Type = MyType<Test1Value>;

interface Test1Value {
  verySpecificData: { a: number; b: boolean; c: null };
}

export class Test1Component extends AbstractComponent<Test1Type> {
  readonly prop = input.required<Test1Type>();
  readonly data = this.prop().value.verySpecificData;
}

type Test2Type = MyType<Test2Value>;

interface Test2Value {
  differentData: { d: string; e: object };
}

export class Test2Component extends AbstractComponent<Test2Type> {
  readonly prop = input.required<Test2Type>();
  readonly data = this.prop().value.differentData;
}

@Component({ standalone: true, template: `` })
export class App {
  components: Record<string, typeof AbstractComponent<MyType>> = {
    'test-1': Test1Component as typeof AbstractComponent,
    'test-2': Test2Component as typeof AbstractComponent,
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


Why are you passing 'test' when we should be passing a type as string, this seems to solve your problem!
The param InputSignal<T> where T is a type, which will be better to be defined as string!
import { Component, InputSignal, input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export abstract class AbstractComponent<T extends string> {
  abstract prop: InputSignal<T>;
}

export class TestComponent extends AbstractComponent<string> {
  prop: InputSignal<string> = input('test');
}

@Component({ standalone: true, template: ``, selector: 'app-root' })
export class App {
  component: Record<string, typeof AbstractComponent<string>> = {
    'test-1': TestComponent,
  };
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

It sure does, but then I can't reliably say that TestComponent['prop'] is of type 'test', which is a requirement for me

@Welnyr is 'test' a interface or a string? its confusing?

In the real project, the T extends string generic is an interface and the test literal type is its sub-type

@Welnyr You are misunderstanding, only when the class is initialized, or component is created it is of type AbstractComponent and you will be able to access the properties Stackblitz if not its just a typeof AbstractComponent, which has the default class properties like name

I really hoped that the most basic setup would be enough to showcase the issue, but apparently I need to make it complex enough to show why I have the restrictions I have. I've made a more complicated setup if you're curious or have advice on how to make it better, but otherwise... i finally found how to solve it

How about letting inference do its job ?
@Component({
  template: '',
})
export class TestComponent extends AbstractComponent<'test'> {
  prop = input<'test'>('test');
}

@Component({ standalone: true, template: `` })
export class App {
  component = {
    'test-1': TestComponent,
  };

  constructor() {
    const myComp = this.component['test-1'] // TestComponent
  }
}


Then there's no strict type-checking if the Record's values extend the TestAbstractComponent class. You can assign something like component = { 'a': null } and no error will be thrown
